# Android app crashes when clicking on the loading icon in notification pane

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version 1.0.27

If you the notification pane and click on the loading icon while it's spinning, the app will cause the app to crash.

```
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=-1
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:310)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.BaseActivity$3.onItemClick(BaseActivity.java:266)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
03-26 22:51:08.331 E/AndroidRuntime(5927): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

(Think I should calm down on finding bugs for a little while? :P)

Comment: Just curious, what made you click the loading icon, of all things? (+1, appears to be legit bug well spotted :))

Comment: Quiet simply I like to try break stuff and curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! It's fixed in the next update, version 1.0.32.

I also left you a note in our source code:

[image]